# Перестала работать логика на login-check

Tags: javascript, авторизация, nestjs

Раньше все работало и работало локально, но после деплоя перестало

```js
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    return request.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Это была старая версия проверки. Сейчас в официальной документации она изменилась на:

```js
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return validateRequest(request);
  }
}
```

Но у меня не видит `validateRequest()` даже после обновления пакета *nestjs*

P.S. При регистрации логин отрабатывает хорошо, а логи чек возвращает 403